# jquery modal ui in ascx asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-mobile, bootstrap-modal, ascx

today i have certain problem using user control (.ascx) in asp.net technology. currently, i have scenario where the ideas are to put modal jquery mobile modal into ascx. then save the data based on click. for this condition, i have this coding

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="IndexPanel1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebPGN.Pages.control.indexPanel1" %>

<style>
    .btn-size {
        width: 50px !important;
    }
</style>

<div>
    <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn" style="float: right; background-color: transparent;" id="state" data-position-to="state"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" style="width: 1000px;" data-history="false">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 style="font-family: '__Helvetica Neue LT Std_5'; font-weight: 500; font-size: 16px;"><i class="icon-edit"></i>&nbsp; Edit Information</h4>
            <a href="#pageone" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right">Close</a>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-responsive" border="0" style="border-color: #FFFFFF;">
                    <tr class="form-group">
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px solid #f4f4f4 !important; font-family: '__Helvetica Neue LT Std_5'; font-weight: 300; width: 10%;">Header Text</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px solid #f4f4f4 !important; font-family: '__Helvetica Neue LT Std_5'; font-weight: 300; width: 30%;">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_Panel1_Header_Eng" Visible="true" EnableViewState="true" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 3%; border-top: 0px solid #f4f4f4 !important;"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px solid #f4f4f4 !important; font-family: '__Helvetica Neue LT Std_5'; font-weight: 300; width: 10%;">Judul Teks</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px solid #f4f4f4 !important; font-family: '__Helvetica Neue LT Std_5'; font-weight: 300; width: 30%;">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_Panel1_Header" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="form-group">
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px solid #f4f4f4 !important; font-family: '__Helvetica Neue LT Std_5'; font-weight: 300; width: 10%;">Body Text</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px solid #f4f4f4 !important; font-family: '__Helvetica Neue LT Std_5'; font-weight: 300; width: 30%;">
                            <textarea rows="6" cols="90" id="txt_Panel1_Body_Eng" runat="server" style="height: 250px;"></textarea>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 3%; border-top: 0px solid #f4f4f4 !important;"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px solid #f4f4f4 !important; font-family: '__Helvetica Neue LT Std_5'; font-weight: 300; width: 10%;">Konten Teks</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px solid #f4f4f4 !important; font-family: '__Helvetica Neue LT Std_5'; font-weight: 300; width: 30%;">
                            <textarea rows="6" cols="90" id="txt_Panel1_Body" runat="server" style="height: 250px;"></textarea>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="form-group">
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px solid #f4f4f4 !important; font-family: '__Helvetica Neue LT Std_5'; font-weight: 300; width: 10%;">Tag</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px solid #f4f4f4 !important; font-family: '__Helvetica Neue LT Std_5'; font-weight: 300; width: 30%;">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_Panel1_Tag_Eng" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 3%; border-top: 0px solid #f4f4f4 !important;"></td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px solid #f4f4f4 !important; font-family: '__Helvetica Neue LT Std_5'; font-weight: 300; width: 10%;">Label</td>
                        <td style="vertical-align: middle; border-top: 0px solid #f4f4f4 !important; font-family: '__Helvetica Neue LT Std_5'; font-weight: 300; width: 30%;">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt_Panel1_Tag" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer" style="border-top: 0px solid #e5e5e5;" id="modal-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#myPopup" data-rel="back" style="color: #fff;">Cancel</a>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#myPopup" ID="btnSaveHomePanel1" data-rel="back" runat="server" style="color: #fff;">Save</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

for some reason, i want to use this ascx for example to send data to the server side. however, i have problem because when using asp.net button, the event doesnot fire back. can anyone give me more advice to accomplish this current condition. or should i use bootstrap modal rather than jquery mobile ui ? and how to use ascx as modal ? thank you very much :)

PS: i am using

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What code are you trying on "save" button click? Also I don't see any asp button in your code

Comment: the template of the design is not from me , so i am so confused about what should i do. i have added the asp.net textbox on the coding but i guess that is the bad way to accomplish it.

Comment: what i want to do is to send the data from input to the c# or precisely the server

Comment: You need to add asp button with`runat='server'` in this ascx with its click event in ascx.cs. The values should be available at server within click event, you may have to find controls or use global variable within ascx.cs. Or you can use jQuery ajax with ashx to send values or with static method(not recommended though).

Comment: can i send it just using onclick using asp:button ?

Comment: Depending on your design and invocation dialog, you can.

Answer (score 0):

you have to try bootstrap Modal like

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<asp:LinkButton ID="btn_SearchCriteria" runat="server" Text="Search Vehicles" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><p class="btn btn-primary">Purchasing Tool</p></asp:LinkButton>


<div aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600">Purchasing Tool and Analysis</h1>
                <button type="button" class="close pull-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            </div>

            <asp:Panel ID="pnlSubItems" runat="server" CssClass="modalBox" Width="100%">
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repVehicleInfo" OnItemDataBound="repVehicleInfo_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <ul class="media-list">
                            <li class="media">
                                <div class="media-left">

                                    <img src="../../images/SystemImages/car-avatar.png" style="width: 250px; height: 200px" />
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_stockno" runat="server" Style="font-weight: 600" Text='<%# Bind("StockNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <%--2001 Holden Astra TS 12/00-12/04--%>
                                    <h1 class="media-heading" style="font-weight: 600">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lbl_heading" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Description") %>'></asp:Label></h1>
                                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                                        <table class="table table-responsive">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Body Style:</td>
                                                <td style="font-weight: 600">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_bodystyle" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BodyType") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Engine:</td>
                                                <td style="font-weight: 600">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_engine" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Engine") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <%--   <td>License No:</td>
                                        <td style="font-weight: 600">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_linceno" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>--%>
                                                <td>Transmission:</td>
                                                <td style="font-weight: 600">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_transmission" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Engine") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <%-- <td>Reg No:</td>
                                        <td style="font-weight: 600">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_regno" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>--%>
                                                <td>Odometer:</td>
                                                <td style="font-weight: 600">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_odometer" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Odometer") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <%-- <td>Color:</td>
                                        <td style="font-weight: 600">
                                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_color" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                        </td>--%>
                                                <td>Purchased From:</td>
                                                <td style="font-weight: 600">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_PurchasedFrom" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PurchasedFrom") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Purchase Amount:</td>
                                                <td style="font-weight: 600">$<asp:Label ID="lbl_PurchaseAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PurchaseAmount") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Sale Amount:</td>
                                                <td style="font-weight: 600">$<asp:Label ID="lbl_SaleAmount" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SalesAmount") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                    <button id="lbtn_makemodel" href="#makemodel" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" data-toggle="modal">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>Make/Model</button>
                                                </td>



                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Estimated Profit:</td>
                                                <td style="font-weight: 600">
                                                    $<asp:Label ID="lbl_Estimatedprofit" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EstimatedProfit") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                    <button id="lbtn_anaylse" href="#anaylse" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-pie-chart" aria-hidden="true"></i>Anaylse</button>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>App Price:</td>
                                                <td style="font-weight: 600">
                                                   $<asp:Label ID="lbl_AppPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PurchaseAmount") %>'></asp:Label>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                                        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repPartsDetail">
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                <ul class="list-group">
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <li class="list-group-item">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Partname" runat="server" Text="Engine" />
                                                    <span class="badge">
                                                        $<asp:Label ID="lbl_partprice" runat="server" Text="0" Style="float: right;" />
                                                    </span>
                                                </li>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                            <FooterTemplate>
                                                </ul>
                                            </FooterTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </li>
             
                        </ul>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>


            </asp:Panel>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

First of all add Bootstrap CSS and Bootstrap JS.
then Use this code 
This code work for me. like when i click on linked button Bootstrap Modal Show 
you can use this Webcontrol Any where and bind data on CodeBhind in ascx.cs file